# What is the difference between non-reflexive or irreflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

What is the difference between a non-reflexive and irreflexive relation? Is one stronger than the other (i.e. all non-reflexive relations are irreflexive or vice-versa)?

Comment: This closure is ridiculous. There is absolutely nothing to be added to the question.

Comment: Isn't this a reasonable question? A relation R on set S can be neither reflexive nor irreflexive. So a Not reflexive relation can be: 1. Not reflexive and not irreflexive,  or 2.  irreflexive . Check Wikipedia https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Reflexive_relation

Answer (score 5):

Is this a trick question? [Original question: *What's the difference between "reflexible" and "irreflexible"?*] None: in both cases, there's no such thing :)
You mean "reflexive" and "irreflexive".

A relation $R \subseteq A \times A $ is *reflexive* on $A$ if $aRa$ for every $a\in A$. Thus $R$ is *not reflexive* on $A$ *iff* for *some* $a\in A, \text{not } aRa$.

A stronger condition than "not reflexive" is *irreflexive*. $R$ is *irreflexive* on $A$ *iff* for all $a\in A, \text{not } aRa$.

If $A\neq \emptyset$, then "$R \text{ is irreflexive on } A$" implies "$R \text{ is not reflexive on } A$", but the converse is not in general true unless $A$ is a singleton.

Comment: Maybe it is a "tricky question" ... consider the order of quantifiers : *irreflexive* : $\forall x \lnot (xRx)$; **not** *reflexive* : $\lnot \forall x (xRx)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA TrickY, yes, it is that.

Answer (score 3):

On set $A=${$1,2,3$}, consider the relations

$(1)$ $R_1=${$(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2)$}

$(2)$ $R_2=${$(1,1),(2,2),(1,2)$}

$(3)$ $R_3=${$(1,2),(2,1),(3,1)$}

$R_1$ is *reflexive*,$R_3$ is *irreflexive* and $R_2$ is *non-reflexive*. Can you see the difference?

Comment: thank you very much for your help